# Is Flume RPC Client Asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, flume

My requirement is to collect data (just Strings) from a high performance system to Hadoop.
I'm using Akka to collect the data and send it to Flume.
However, for experimentation purpose, I want to see if Flume alone will do the job. I have the FlumeRPCClient ready that will communicate to a cluster of Flume collectors.

My client extends org.apache.flume.api.LoadBalancingRpcClient.

The question is, whether the FlumeRPCClient is asynchronous. If it is not, the sender will have a performance hit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to guarantee event delivery flume agent need to store event from your FlumeRPCClient into the channel (file or memory channel, which depends on your configuration of receiving agent). 
So, it should block until event is accepted and stored in channel. You may want to group events into batches to increase performance or simply dump them to rotated files and read by separate flume agent process.

Comment: Thanks. That means I cannot go for this approach. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the asynchronous appender from Log4j2. It uses Disruptor to pipe events through to whatever appender you select.

You would lose the guarantee that you durably store all events (because any events that happen to be in Disruptor if the process failed will be lost). However, if you want maximum performance you have to make this tradeoff anyway.